# Android app displaying list of video from YouTube playlist using YouTube API

Tags: api, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to make an app which shows video from my YouTube channel or from my playlist using using YouTube API..

the app should be like this..
app should display list of all video in playlist and when user click on any video it should be played...

how can i do this app ?

if you know solution please send both java and xml code for this..  or send a link from where i can download source code

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems), it returns all the videos from your playlist.

> "A playlistItem resource identifies another resource, such as a video,
>   that is included in a playlist. In addition, the playlistItem resource
>   contains details about the included resource that pertain specifically
>   to how that resource is used in that playlist."

For Java code samples, checkout the Official [Youtube api-samples/java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java) for code reference.